# auto x = make_x(...) and this

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class template `S<T>` and because the template parameter is sometimes hard write explicitly I also have a little helper function `makeS(...)` to deduce the template parameter.

Now the problem is that the constructor of `S` has a "side effect": it adds itself to a `map` which then will later be used to iterate over all instances of `S`. But this effectively makes `S<T> s{...};` very different from `auto s = makeS(...);` (if RVO is not used).

Here is some code which hopefully shows what I'm trying to do. (Note: in the actual program, `S` has more than a single template parameter and all will be deduced in `makeS`)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {}

    virtual void f() const = 0;
};

static map<string, Base*> Map;

template <typename T>
struct S : Base
{
    T Func;
    Base* This;

    S(string const& name, T func) : Func(std::move(func)), This(this)
    {
        //
        // Automatically add this struct to Map...
        //

        Map.insert({name, this});
    }

    virtual void f() const override { Func(); }
};

template <typename T>
S<T> makeS(std::string const& name, T func)
{
    return S<T>(name, std::move(func));
}

void func1()
{
    std::cout << "func1\n";
}

int main()
{
    struct Func2
    {
        void operator ()() const {
            std::cout << "func2\n";
        }
    };

    //
    // This is not possible:
    //
    // S< ??? > s("s", [](){});
    //
    // This would be ok:
    //
    // auto F = [](){};
    // S<decltype(F)> s("s", F);
    //

    auto s1 = makeS("s1", func1);
    auto s2 = makeS("s2", Func2());
    auto s3 = makeS("s3", [](){ std::cout << "func3\n"; });

    //
    // Manually adding s1,... to the Map is ok, but that's what
    // I want to avoid...
    //
    // Map.insert({"s1", &s1});
    // ...
    //

    assert(&s1 == s1.This);
    assert(&s2 == s2.This);
    assert(&s3 == s3.This);

    for (auto&& I : Map)
    {
        I.second->f();
    }
}
```

As I understand it, the map will only contain valid pointers if RVO is used in `auto s1 = makeS(...)` etc. and this is not guaranteed.

Is there a way to deduce the template parameters while at the same time avoiding the need to manually register `s1,...`?

Comment: Just update the `this` value in the map on move? Your code is going to be very very brittle otherwise.

Comment: @Xeo Yes this would be possible but then I'd need to store a reference to the map and perform a lookup on each move. (In the actual program the map is not a global variable.)

Comment: 1) You shouldn't use templates just cuz its hard to write out the type, you should use typedefs/using statements cuz the type is hard to write out. 2) Side effects in constructors are ALWAYS brittle.

Comment: In C++11, you could fix this by first disabling the copy constructor and then supplying a move constructor that updates the ptr location...while this would work, I still say the side effect in the constructor is broken as hell.

Comment: Yes I know that using the this pointer in the constructor is not the best option. But is there a another way to achieve the same effect? I.e. automatically register the constructed object?

Comment: You don't need to store the map or make a lookup every time. All you need is a reference (read: pointer / iterator) to the node that contains that instance's info. This makes updating a constant process and is perfectly safe, as nodes are only invalidated when they are erased. That way, you won't even need to actually store the name itself in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is you failed to implement the rule of 3.  If your destructor needs non-trivial behavior (and if you register yourself in the constructor, this is the case), you must either implement or block assignment and copy construct (and/or move-assign and move-construct).

In this case, we can implement a `move`-construct and block `move`-assign, and copy construct and copy assign are implicitly blocked.

First, add `name` to `S`.  Then implement a `move` constructor.

```
template <typename T>
struct S : Base
{
  std::string Name;
  T Func;
  Base* This; // ?? why ?? this looks both dangerous and useless at the same time!
  S( S&& s ): Name(std::move(s.Name)), Func(std::move(s.Func)), This(this) {
    s.clear(); // technically `move` need not clear.
    map[Name] = this; // overwrite
  }
  S& operator=(S&& s) = delete; // or implement it
```

now your object is `move`able, and when `move`d it updates the `Map`.  `~S` should, I assume, unregister from `Map` -- detect if your `name` is empty (and assert at construction you gain a non-empty name), and if it is don't unregister (as you where already `move`d from).

Now `move`-construct and elided-construct have the same semantics.  RVO failure results in some inefficiency, but no logical failure.  Plus, your type is now `move`able, which tends to be really useful.

Comment: The This member is just to make the asserts in the sample code work. It's not present in the real code. And I already store the name in class S. I don't do anything in the destructor, the map does not outlive s1,... I really should have been more clear... But yes, I guess I have to implement copy and/or move ctor and op= then.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to maintain object identity, use can use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<S<T>> makeS(std::string const& name, T func)
{
    return { new S<T>(name, std::move(func)) };
}
```

Now moving the pointer from place to place won't move the object; the pointer kept in the map will stay valid.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions to improve your code:
1) Get rid of the side effect in the constructor. Create objects in a factory method only (`makeS` in your code; you can make it a static member function of `S`) and register the `S` objects in that method. To disable object creation in different ways make constructor(s) private.

2) Disable `S` objects copying/moving and handle the objects for example as `shared_ptr`/`unique_ptr<S>` only. When you disable copying/moving you avoid the problem when your map contains a pointer to invalid objects and now you don't need to rely on RVO.

3) Use `std::function<void()>` instead of `T Func;`. In that case your class don't need to be a template class (or it will have less template arguments). That will simplify your code.